# Price: In or For

Tags: prepositions

When talking about price, we usually use **for**  *... for $1* or *...for a dollar*.

But in the following question using **for** sounds strange to me. I think **in** suits better. Maybe, it's because of my first language.

> What would you buy, an apple in $1 or an apple, a cherry and an orange in $1?

**for** sounds natural if rephrased

> What would you buy for a dollar, an apple or an apple, a cherry and an orange?

Is it ok to say, use only **for** when talking about price?

Comment: ’In’ is incorrect ’for’ may sound strange but is the right choice.

Comment: "In" is out....

Comment: I'd probably rephrase entirely, to say *which would you buy: an apple **that costs** one dollar, or an apple, a cherry, and an orange **that cost** one dollar?* Or possibly *an apple **selling for** a dollar, or an apple, a cherry, & an orange **that are selling (together) for** a dollar*.

Comment: *For* doesn't sound strange to me when used in your  quote. *In* isn't idiomatic there - it suggests something more literal, like an oversized $1 coin (like a chocolate egg) with an apple inside.